# Connection to multiple MongoDB DataBases Java

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl

I have 2 different databases (firstDB , secondDB), connecting separately to each of them works correctly, but if in one session I try to connect to the second I get an error, I connect to the first one without problems

```
public static MongoDatabase dbConnect() {
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "src/main/resources/firstDB.pkcs12");
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "qwerty");
       ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(System.getenv("FirstMongoDB_DEV"));
       CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
       CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
               pojoCodecRegistry);

       MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
               .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
               .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
               .build();
       return MongoClients.create(clientSettings).getDatabase("firstDB");

   }
```

code to connect is similar for both, so if i'll call firstDB connect it work fine and if after that i call connect to secondDB i get com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
If i swap the connections, first to the secondDB then to the firstDB, I'll get the same result

Comment: In general, you can get reference to multiple databases with the same `MongoClient` instance.

Comment: @prasad_ How do this with 2 different connection String? both of them has own login/pass

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that JVM does not know how to dynamically change the keyStore, library that [helped](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart)